# Angularjs next and previous button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create next and previous button in angular. I am new in programming. I have written a program. If I use custom array `$scope.data = []` it works. When I use `$http` it is not working please help to solve this.

**Controller.js**

```
var app=angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', function ($scope, $filter, $http) {
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.pageSize = 2;

    $scope.numberOfPages=function(){
        return Math.ceil($scope.pageSize);                
    }
    /*$scope.data = [
    { title: 'Reggae', id: 1 },
    { title: 'Chill', id: 2 },
    { title: 'Dubstep', id: 3 },
    { title: 'Indie', id: 4 },
    { title: 'Rap', id: 5 },
    { title: 'Cowbell', id: 6 }
  ];*/
               $http.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bantic/imdb-data-scraping/master/data/movies.json')
          .then(function(response){
            $scope.data = response.data;
          });

}]);


app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```

**index.htlm**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in data  | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
            {{item.title}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage-1">
        Previous
    </button>
    {{currentPage+1}}/{{numberOfPages()}}
    <button ng-disabled="currentPage >= getData().length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage+1">
        Next
  </button>
</div>
```

**Output**

```
Previous {{currentPage+1}}/{{numberOfPages()}} Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You had messed up in dependency sequence while injecting & using them in controller factory function. Ensure that the injected dependency should be used in same order as they are injected.

You were injecting `'$scope', '$http', '$filter'` & using inside controller factory function like `function($scope, $filter, $http) {` where `$filter` had instance of `$http` & `$http` has instance of `$filter`.

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter','$http', function ($scope, $filter, $http) {
```

Comment: i am new in programing so i can understand.

Comment: @joydee do accept answer by clicking on right below the upvote count, THanks

Answer (score 0):

Note that your $http request is returning an object and not an array. You cannot use splice on objects (Like you do in the filter) so that could be an additional cause why this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code:

```
      $http.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bantic/imdb-data-scraping/master/data/movies.json')
      .then(function(response){
        $scope.data = response.data;
      });
```

with this code, and it should work. Basically, your $http request was returning object, and not an array and you cannot perform `splice` operation on object. Plus, the response format was different from what you're using in `$scope.data`:

```
 $http.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bantic/imdb-data-scraping/master/data/movies.json')
      .then(function(response)
{
  var data = [];
  response.data.forEach(function(movieObj, yearKey)
  {
   var temp = {};
   temp.title = movieObj.title;
   temp.id = movieObj.imdbId;
   data.push(temp);
  });
  $scope.data = data;
});
```